# Why default props is not accessible in validate function?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Why is default props not accessible in validate function? try, to access default props in validate function but not able, please help?
on the other hand, can access in render function.

```
const validate = (values, props) => {
    console.log('Default Props : ', props.name); // here not accessible
};

Test.defaultProps = {
    name: 'Test',
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'test',
    validate
})(Test);
```

Comment: Is the console log firing? What exactly does it log?

Comment: it's output is Default Props : undefined

Comment: @223seneca, please help it is urgent.